# How Does One Create A Cellulose Ingredient For Use In The Creation Of Glucose?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry

I am attempting to begin synthesizing glucose, however I will require a form of ball milled cellulose as a main ingredient. Having been said, what methods would be recommended to create the Cellulose? If we were to use grass clippings or cotton as our source for example, what steps would we take in order to gain the desired material from the aforementioned source?

Comment: How much equipment do you have? Do you have access to standard lab equipment? Might be really helpful to know for the answerer.

Comment: Fairly standard as comparable to high school equipment.

Answer (score 3):

[Cotton wool](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cotton+wool), also called "purified cotton", is inexpensive and available at pharmacies ("chemists" in the UK). I could not find the percentage of impurities (probably lignin and minerals), but it is considered [one of the purest forms of cellulose commercially available](https://books.google.com/books?id=nuxsAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA772&lpg=PA772&dq=%22cotton%20wool%22%20cellulose%20lignin%20impurities&source=bl&ots=kCLojVzDRL&sig=JiGO7pZN7bjNdtV3jvWYS2SYPj0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=A_mfVYy0FIymgwTyy4XwBg&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22cotton%20wool%22%20cellulose%20lignin%20impurities&f=false), and should not need pretreatment to make glucose.